# How to OR in mongo $test search with Phrases

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

as an example in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases):

> > "\"ssl certificate\" authority key"
>
> The $text operator searches for the phrase "ssl certificate" and ("authority" or "key" or "ssl" or "certificate" ).

is there a method to search "ssl certificate" or "authority" or "key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a text search involving any phrase matches will always start with only the documents which have the phrase(s). You might be able to work around this issue by using the aggregation framework? If your text index is on the field 'textField', you could do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$text: {$search: "ssl certificate authority key"}}},
  {$match: {$or: [
    {textField: {$regex: /ssl certificate/}},
    {textField: {$regex: /authority/}},
    {textField: {$regex: /key/}}
  ]}}
])
```